# Efficiently split pandas dataframe and apply method to sub-sets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In Pandas, I want to:

- randomly select a sample from a dataframe (with a single column)
- split this sample into **nr_of_chunks** chunks with each chunk containing **items_per_chunk**
- compute the mean of each chunk
- and plot it into a histogram

As long as I increase **items_per_chunk** but keep **nr_of_chunks** constant, the histogram of the means of each chunk should plot as a narrowing bell curve.

I came up with the following Pandas, Numpy, Seaborn approach, which looks inefficient or not very clever to me:

```py
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv')

nr_of_chunks = 1000

for items_per_chunk in [1, 5, 20]:
  sample = df.sample(nr_of_chunks * items_per_chunk)
  chunks = np.array_split(sample, nr_of_chunks)
  mean_of_chunks = [chunk.mean() for chunk in chunks]

  sns.distplot(mean_of_chunks)
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a better way to do it? For example, I expect there is a way to directly apply the mean function to each chunk while splitting the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After resetting the index of `sample` to a regular `RangeIndex`, you can simply [`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by the index floor-divided by `items_per_chunk`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv')

nr_of_chunks = 1000

for items_per_chunk in [1, 5, 20]:
  sample = df.sample(nr_of_chunks * items_per_chunk).reset_index(drop=True)
  mean_of_chunks = sample.groupby(sample.index // items_per_chunk).mean()

  sns.distplot(mean_of_chunks)
```